# Сохранить vector в файл и считать оттуда

Tags: c++

Имеется структура:

```
struct str
{
int a;
bool b;
};
```

Также есть вторая:

```
struct str2
{
int c;
int d[5];
std::vector<str>vec;
};
```

На её основе строится вектор:

```
std::vector<str2>vec_2;
```

Нужно сохранить этот вектор в файл, а также считать из файла обратно в память.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно определить методы чтения/записи вашей структуры. Для этой цели хорошо подходят операторы `<<` и `>>`.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const str &value){
    os << value.a << value.b;
    return os; 
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, str &value){
    is >> value.a >> value.b;
    return is; 
}
```

Теперь писать структуру в файл можно так:

```
std::fstream ofs("file");
str s;
ofs << s;
```

а читать так:

```
std::fstream ifs("file");
str s;
ifs >> s;
```

Чтобы записать вектор структур в файл, можно сделать так:

```
std::fstream ofs("file");
std::vector<str> v = {...};
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<str>(ofs));
```

Чтобы прочитать вектор структур, можно сделать так:

```
std::fstream ifs("file");
std::vector<str> v;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<str>(ifs), std::istream_iterator<str>(), std::back_inserter(v));
```

Это была инструкция для `str`. Вам нужно выполнить аналогичные действия и для `str2`.

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы хотите, называется сериализациея/десериализация. Существует довольно много решений на этот счет, например, boost::serialization.

Одним из простых кросплатформенных способов сериализации является использование QDataStream и перегрузка `operator <<` и `operator >>` для пользовательских типов. Любой массив записывается в виде

```
stream << std::int64_t{array.size};
for(auto&& x: array)
  stream << x;
```

и считывается в обратном порядке, для контейнеров из Qt уже предусмотрены перегрузки.

Пример перегрузок:

```
QDataStream& operator << (QDataStream& stream, const str& rha){
  return stream 
    << int64_t{rha.a}
    << rha.b;
}

QDataStream& operator >> (QDataStream& stream, const str& rha){
  int64_t a; // Нужен платформонезависимый тип
  stream >> a;
  rha.a = a;
  stream >> rha.b;
  return  stream;
}

str str_1 {123, false};
str str_2;
{
  File file("file.dat");
  file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  QDataStream out(&file);
  out << str1; 
}
{
  File file("file.dat");
  file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  QDataStream in(&file);
  in >> str2; 
}
```

Для обработки ошибок можно бросать исключения (без этого есть шанс заполнить все структуры нулями и долго искать ошибку).

Строки таким образом сериализовывать нельзя, нужно преобразовывать их в нормальный массив, например, в utf8, и уже его записывать, т.к. чтение и запись строк в потоки обычно не симметричны.

То же самое можно делать и со стандартными потоками, но там есть проблема с кросплатформенностью.